# Minikube "icacls failed applying permissions "

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

suddently, this error message started appearing when starting minikube:

```
* Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB) .../ E0124 18:28:01.039963    8724 kic.go:267] icacls failed applying permissions - err - [%!s(<nil>)], output - [file elaborato: C:\Users\user\.minikube\machines\minikube\id_rsa
Elaborazione completata per 1 file. Elaborazione non riuscita per 0 file]
```

It's strange because it gives an error, but also sais that 1 file has been elaborated correctly.
Minikube is not behaving strange though. Should I just ignore this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it is a known issue (and will be fixed in 1.26.0): https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13868